# Visual Studio 2022 not showing during sandcastle installation

Tags: package, sandcastle

I'm trying to install sandcastle for my Visual Studio 2022. during the installation after installing the "Sandcastle Help File Builder" i'm supposed to install a package for Visual Studio,  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQNg.jpg
But when i try to install the package i only get 2019 as an option : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTChf.jpg
(sorry need 10 rep to post pictures)

I need to use sandcastle on 2022 but i can't see anybody with a similar issue online.
I'm not sure what to do or where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Sandcastle GitHub page: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB
I think there is a 2022 plug in